# How does one use varied array database insert using prepared statements?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

Below is a set of functions relating to my issue, the `insert_array` function. Before it is asked, yes I have attempted to error output it all however after cleaning the single small error I found it returns nothing for me, and I cleaned it out for your reading convenience. Do not mock the messy  code(< Is Amateur) but what am I doing wrong? I am attempting to insert a dynamic array using a whitelist for the field names and then using the call_user_func_array as a way to input the data. However It does nothing, doesn't even error.

I assume I made a small typo that causes some check to fail. How would I properly get the unspecified array tucked into the database?

```
function field_whitelist($funcdb, $field) {
    $query = mysqli_query($funcdb,"SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database1' AND `TABLE_NAME`='table1';");
    $whitelist = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
        $whitelist[] = $row[0];
    }
    if (empty(array_diff($field, $whitelist) === false)) {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}

function get_array_types($array) {
    $rstring = '';
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if (is_int($value)) {
            $value = 'i';
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $value = 's';
        }
        $rstring = $rstring.$value;
        unset($value);
    }
    return $rstring;
}

function insert_array($inputarray, $funcdb) {
    array_walk($inputarray, 'array_sanitize', $funcdb);
    $data_array = array();

    foreach ($inputarray as &$array_val) {
        $data_array[] = '?';
    }

    $fields = implode(', ', array_keys($inputarray));
    $data = implode(', ', $data_array);
    $type = get_array_types($inputarray);

    if (field_whitelist($funcdb, array_keys($inputarray)) === true) {
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($funcdb, "INSERT INTO table1 (".$fields.") VALUES (".$data.")")) {
            call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge (array($stmt, $type), $inputarray));
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try doing a var_dump on the merged array that you use call_user_func_array on to see what the actual resulting array is. There's probably a problem in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in your title is "with difficulty". I suspect that the problem here is to do with [`bind_param` only accepting parameters passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)  (mentioned in one of the notes on that page). There are some really helpful comments on that page, suggesting solutions to this problem. I would recommend checking them out.

One of the suggestions is to try something like this:

```
$params = array_merge(array($stmt, $type), $inputarray);
$refs = array();
foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    $refs[$key] = &$params[$key]; 
}
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $refs);
```

I have used something similar to this in the past and it worked for me.

Comment: While your answer did help me, it was actually a misplaced bracket causing my problems.